# MultiThreading join(Long millis) operation

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

straight to question. is `Thread.join(x)` starting the count from the moment `start()` method is called or from the moment `join(x)` method is called?

To demonstrate: which of the following solutions is the correct way of doing it?

```
        Set<Thread> myThreads=new HashSet<Thread>();
        for(Task t : tasks){
            try{
                Thread thread=new ConcurrentTask(t);
                thread.start();
                myThreads.add(thread);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch(Exception e){

            }
        }
 //solution 1:
        for(Thread t: myThreads){
           try{
              t.join(10000) //wait for at most 10 seconds
           }catch(Exception e){}
        }
 //solution 2:
        long maxWaitTime=System.currentTimeMillis()+ (10*1000);//max wait is 10 seconds;
        for(Thread t: myThreads){
            long threadWait=maxWaitTime - System.currentTimeMillis();
            if(threadWait<100){
                threadWait=100;
            }
           try{
              t.join(threadWait) //wait for at most 10 seconds
           }catch(Exception e){}

        }
```

Comment: [_Waits at most millis milliseconds for this thread to die. A timeout of 0 means to wait forever._](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join-long-) It starts counting when `join` is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing multiple threads and it looks like the maximum wait time for all threads is supposed to be 10 seconds, then option 2 is correct. Wait time is from the wait execution, it does not check on total thread execution time.

Comment: so , lets say using solution 1, if there are 10 threads, then program could go on for 100 seconds. is that right?

Comment: Worst case, yes, plus any overhead between each wait. For #2, worst case scenario is 10 seconds + .1 seconds x (# of threads - 1) plus any overhead.